# Amazon S3 Bucket Region Selection

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have users across the world and they GET object from Amazon S3 buckets. So I'd like to set up 4 different buckets in different regions (3 of them are replications). Cloudfront is not my choice since the first-time request latency is still high. Is there any service that can receive the GET request from the user, automatically decide which bucket it should get files from with the fastest speed, GET files from that bucket and then send back the file to the user?

I have looked up Route 53, but it's all about hosting a website. My case is a mobile app. I just want to get the files from the server.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Doesn't matter if it's a website or a mobile app; you *can* do this with Route53. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html#routing-policy-latency

Comment: You mean CNAME records to the bucket names with latency based routing @ceejayoz?

Answer (score 3):

You can deploy your application in the specific regions you want and make sure in code that the files are come from the same region bucket.
Then you can use Route53 GeoLocation/Weighted routing policy and then based on your users location the request will go to that region and be processed accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But Route 53 needs the S3 bucket to be a website endpoint. Then I can't getObject and putObject anymore using that website endpoint.

Comment: You will have to write the code to PUT or GET the objects from S3 in your website. So whenever a request to GET or PUT the object comes then your code will handle it.